# Creating a remote host file explorer using jsch

Tags: java, user-interface, jsch

In a project Im working on I included the functionality of transfering files between the local machine and a remote host. Still, the end users dont use it, because they dont like having to type in filepaths or filenames. For example, when they want to copy a remote file to their local machine, i display a textbox and ask them to type in the path o the file they want to copy. Because of that the users tend to use other programs, like WinSCP.

I want to improve the user experience. Im thinking about including a file explorer panel in swing, similar to what WinSCP has to offer. How could I do that? I couldnt find any open source projects/libraries that fit my needs, and I dont really have an idea on how to write that using jsch. How could I do that?

Comment: Did you look at the example section on JSCH http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html ?  Also, I recommend looking into JCIFS (http://jcifs.samba.org/), I think that's a much better option.

Comment: @CPU 100 I am not free to change the protocol I am using, it has to be sftp, so I guess jcifs does not cut it. I saw all the examples on the jsch site - but that does not help me. I already have a working file send to/download from remote, I can execute shell commands on the remote host. The problem is that I want to pack this functionality in a useable interface. Think "JFilechooser for remote host files, using jsch" - thats the sort of thing I need. I could try to implement it from scratch, but thats a LOT of work, and im looking for something easier/less tiresome.

Comment: For any future visitors, I had to implement the "RemoteJFileChooser" from scratch.